# Invoke an alert on an href, then continue to a new page

Tags: javascript, mootools, alerts

I have a link to a page which invokes the 'Sexy Alert Box' script to pop a message asking if users agree to Terms and Conditions with options "I Agree" and "Cancel".

I've got that much going but now **I need for the "I Agree" option to send them to a new page**. ("Cancel" returns the user the current page.)

Something to do with `document.location.href`?

I am using the mootools framework.

[Sexy Alert Box 1.2 mootools & jQuery](http://www.coders.me/web-html-js-css/javascript/sexy-alert-box-12-mootools-jquery)

Here's the code:

```
<a href="#" 
    onclick="Sexy.confirm('Do you agree to the terms and conditions?', {
        textBoxBtnOk: 'I Agree', // goes to www.newpage.com
        textBoxBtnCancel: 'Cancel' // return to current page    
    });">Link</a>
```

Comment: That should really be `<a href="newpage.com" onclick="...">`, so that non-js users don't end up with non-functioning link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard, built-in javascript `confirm` function will return true or false, depending on the button pushed (this is a *synchronous* action), but this `Sexy.confirm` plugin looks like something that is going to return its choice via callback functions (it will be an *asynchronous* action).

For example,

```
function doConfirm() {
    Sexy.confirm('Do you agree to the terms and conditions?', {
        textBoxBtnOk: 'I Agree',
        textBoxBtnCancel: 'Cancel',
        onComplete: function(returnvalue) {
            // here is where you act, after user has made a choice...
            if (returnvalue) {
                //alert ("pressed OK");
                window.location.href = '/page1/';
            }
            else {
                //alert("pressed Cancel");
                window.location.href = '/page2/';
            }
        }
    });
    return false; // this is to cancel the native click event
}
```

And then you can make your link tags a little nicer,

```
<a href="#" onclick="return doConfirm();">Link</a>
```

Good luck!

Comment: P.S., you should also strongly consider changing the `href="#"` to point to a real href, so that user-agents without javascript can still access the site.

Answer (score 1):

With Mootools:

Use for HTML

```
<a class="confirm" href="www.google.fr">Google Fr</a>
<a class="confirm" href="www.google.be">Google Be</a>
```

And JavaScript

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    $$('a.confirm').each(function (el) {
        el.addEvent('click', function (e) {
            e.stop();
            Sexy.confirm('<h1>Etes-vous sur de vouloir suivre ce lien ?</h1>',{ 
                onComplete: function(returnvalue) {
                    if (returnvalue) {
                        window.location.href = el.get('href');
                    }
                },
                textBoxBtnOk: 'Oui',
                textBoxBtnCancel: 'Non'
            });
        });
    });
});
```